# Include a jar archive without including in environment variables

Tags: java, command-line, jar

I want to include org.eclipse.swt.3-1.jar in a .java file without put it in my environment variables? How can I do this?

The java src I want to try is [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/Implementsawebbrowser2.htm).

I have just this file as a .java file and I have from here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgeclipseswt31jar.htm the org.eclipse file. Both in the same directory.

PS: I compile on the command line and don't use Eclipse.

Comment: What does your directory structure look like, what command(s) are you currently running, and what error(s) do you get?

Comment: I tried all the (windows) command provided in the linked question and the error is just that the classes couldnt be found. its just 2 files, the .jar and a .java - both in the same directory

Answer (score 2):

> its just 2 files, the .jar and a .java - both in the same directory

Then you need to first compile the java source (.java) file into a class file (.class) file. You use the `javac` command from the JDK and something like

```
javac -cp org.eclipse.swt.3-1.jar;. file.java
```

Then your directory should contain 3 files, te .jar and .java and a .class file. Then

```
java -cp org.eclipse.swt.3-1.jar;. file
```

Comment: Thank you, but finally i want to create my own jar file containing it all that my friends can also use it. I know how to crate a  usual jar file but how to do it including the eclipse.swt?

Comment: i wrote a link in my question referenncing to another answer. the commands provided there i have tried. I want to include the eclipse.swt in my java program and finaly build my own jar file of it.

Comment: A jar file is just a zip file with extra metadata. Perhaps you could try something else before asking a completely different question. You had a source file. Presumably you now have a working program. Now you need to learn about [packaging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html).

Comment: sorry but i tried to just put it together in the same directory and imported the swt classes as `import org.eclipse.swt.SWT` and i tried `javac -cp ".:org.eclipse.swt.jar" file.java` and also `javac -cp .;org.eclipse.swt.jar file.java` (without slashes) i cant find any other tips.

Comment: but i cant compile my java source to a class file because the used classes couldnt be found?!

Comment: So can you tell me why i couldnt compile my java source with that?

Comment: SWT uses native code, and requires a fair bit more then one jar. You haven't posted any code as of yet...

Comment: i added links, cant you see them? i used exactly that code and just changed a view strings. so you mean when i only have this .jar file it seems that i just downloaded the wrong jar file, right? should i post the code anymore?